# Bases for the image and the kernel of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let the linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^3  \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be given by $$T(x,y,z)=(x+y+z,x+2y-3z,2x+3y-2z,3x+4y-z)$$ Find the basis for the image and kernel of T.

HINT: First find the matrix for T in the usual basis.

I understand how to find the kernel and image from a matrix.  What I do not understand is how to find the matrix for T.  My only idea so far is that $$(x+y+z)e_1+(x+2y-3z)e_2+(2x+3y-2z)e_3+(3x+4y-z)e_4$$ gives me the matrix for T in the usual basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $T(1,0,0), T(0,1,0), T(0,0,1)$ and assign each vector to the column of the transformation matrix leaving you with

$$T\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&-3\\2&3&-2\\3&4&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$

In general in order to find this matrix write $A = [T(e_1)\ \ \ \   T(e_2) \ \ \ \ ... \ \ \ \ T(e_n)]$ whose $jth$ column is the vector $T(e_j)$ of the idendity matrix $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For more info check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiuhTj0zCf4) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfVY7cW7VLQ).

Answer (score 1):

The associated matrix to a linear operator is defined by $T_{ij} = T(e_j)_i$ (This means that you write $T(e_j) = \sum_{k} T_{kj}e_k$ and then take the transpose matrix). So you get:

$$
T
=
\begin{pmatrix}
T(1,0,0)_1 & T(0,1,0)_1 & T(0,0,1)_1 \\ 
T(1,0,0)_2 & T(0,1,0)_2 & T(0,0,1)_2 \\ 
T(1,0,0)_3 & T(0,1,0)_3 & T(0,0,1)_3 \\
T(1,0,0)_4 & T(0,1,0)_4 & T(0,0,1)_4
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &  1 \\
1 & 2 & -3 \\ 
2 & 3 & -2 \\
3 & 4 & -1
\end{pmatrix} 
$$